# Integration involving negative roots yields two answers?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers

I have this problem that is driving me insane.

I am asked to evaluate:

$$\int^1_{-1} \sqrt[3]{t} -2 \ dt$$

Now I evaluate this correctly to

$$[\frac{3^{4/3}t}{4}-2t]^1_{-1}$$

From here I work this problem has follows:

$$[\frac{3(1)^{4/3}}{4}-2(1)]-[\frac{3(-1)^{4/3}}{4}-2(-1)]$$

$\Longrightarrow$ $$[\frac{3}{4}-2]-[\frac{3}{4}+2]$$

$\Longrightarrow$ $$-4$$

Now the answer I get on online calculators(Wolfram, http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=8ab70731b1553f17c11a3bbc87e0b605) is

[image]

When it comes to $(-1)^{4/3}$ it should equal to $1$, because $-1^4=1$ and$\sqrt[3]1=1$
and equivalent is the reasoning $\sqrt[3]-1=-1$ and $-1^4=1$

Is there something I am missing or another way to evaluate $(-1)^{4/3}$? And if so what makes that answer stronger than this one? In other words shouldn't both answers be valid? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The answer that Wolfram gives is not correct in the context.

Note that there are also two complex third roots of $-1$, they are $$\frac{1 + i \sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{1 - i \sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Wolfram is using the first of these.

Answer (score 1):

Just notice that Wolfram Alpha reads $\sqrt[3]{\cdot}$ as the complex principal cubic root. Then, if you are working with a real valued function, your answer is right.